# Creating space under/over paragraphs, tables etc

Tags: r, officer

I cant figure out from the officer manual or function reference, if it is possible to create space between objects in a word document? By space i mean a function that would equal pressing "enter" while writing.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body_add_par(value="")
```

should do the job.

eg.

```
myDoc <- myDoc %>%
  body_add_par(value = "example1")
  body_add_par(value = "")
  body_add_par(value = "example1")
```

You can use this to create spaces after tables and other objects.

Comment: Perfect! That worked exactly how i wished! Thank you! @Jamsandwich

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation using /r/n will do the work . Example

**ftext(", \r\nhow are you?", prop = bold_face ) )**